# Display data from database (using mongodb) in hbs/html file Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I started studying node.js, and now I'm trying to do a "Todo-App".

I'm trying to find the best way to transfer data from my database (using mongodb) into my hbs files, so I could display it.

From the server.js -> server to the hbs -> client (correct to me if I'm wrong please, by assuming that server.js is the server of course and the hbs file is the client)

So, I succeeded to do it by passing an array.
but when I'm trying to display in html desing, it just looking bad.

The code:

```
app.get('/allTasks',(req,res)=>{ //get (go to) the allTasks (hbs file)
   Todo.find().then((todos) => {
     console.log(todos);
     var arrayOfTodos = [];
     todos.forEach(function(element){
       console.log("\n\n\n\n\n elemnt details: ",element.text + "\n",element.completed+"\n");
       arrayOfTodos.push(element.text,element.completed);
      });
      res.render("allTasks.hbs", {
        pageTitle: "Your tasks: ",
        todos: arrayOfTodos
        });
    });

});
```

The result is:

[You can see a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgPLA.png)

As you can see, its just looking bad... cause it just display an array,
an I want to display each task seperately.
Any tips?

Thanks a lot,
Sagiv

Comment: Hey guys, the problem isnt solve yet. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using push just do:

```
Todo.find().toArray(function(err, result){
   arrayOfTodos = result;
})
```

Once you have your array, the design got nothing to do with mongodb. You will need to learn how to use your render technology. You need to touch your html template, so you should start by posting that.

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion (and already saw it in other web sites) but unfortunately it did not succeed.

it return error: "TypeError: Todo.find(...).toArray is not a function"

Comment: And in addition to your comment, you said that the way im doing it, it fine but i have to learn html and how to display the data?
I mean - the server is fine and there is nothing to do more than that?

Comment: Yes, once you have the array, you are basically printing it inside a paragraph element. You will need to loop through it, and maybe create a <ul> and for each todo create a <li>. But you will need to learn how to do it in Handlebars or use Vue or Angular or something. In Vue.js is very easy using v-for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it by your way and succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved.
I just had to learn how to handle the data in the hbs side.
so the code is: (in hbs)

```
    {{#each todos}}
{{missionNumber}} <br>
{{text}}<br>
completed = {{completed}}<br><br>
   {{/each}}
```

as you can see, the each is a loop , that pass on the todos parameter (my array)
and i just have to display the data in the way i want it to be displayed.

thanks for your help.